# "The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files: node_modules" while trying to deploy with 'gh-pages'

Tags: github, npm, deployment, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my app to github, but I meet this mistake:

```
$ npm run deploy

> git-repository@1.0.0 deploy C:\Users\zarin\Desktop\projects\GIT repository
> gh-pages -d dist

The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
node_modules

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! git-repository@1.0.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the git-repository@1.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zarin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-28T16_31_01_911Z-debug.log
```

Not really sure what to do with node_modules here

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this error. I deleted the following folders and re-ran the command:

dist

node_modules/.cache

It deployed the app successfully.