# gh-pages - deploy stops on creating a branch

Tags: github, create-react-app, github-pages

I have been trying to deploy my React App to Github Pages using gh-pages.

Here is my setup:
gh-pages": "^5.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
After running "npm run deploy", in the terminal I see:

gh-pages -d build

The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
node_modules

---

and the process stops, and I end up on the gh-pages branch with all my src files being in the stagging area. No branch is created in github repo.

I have tried too look it up on the Youtube and the Internet and I clearly see that process should end with "Published" message, with the user not being stuck on gh-pages branch in their text editor.

Comment: Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75563910/6309) help?

Comment: @VonC I gave it a shoot and it actually worked! Many thanks! :)