# Issue with npm gh-pages and deployment

Tags: npm, github-actions, github-pages, parceljs

I've been dealing with an issue when using the `gh-pages` npm module wherein running `npm run deploy` is not triggering deployment on GitHub reliably - sometimes it works, most of the time it doesn't.

I've tried running

```
NODE_DEBUG=gh-pages npm run deploy
```

Which outputs

```
GH-PAGES 28395: Cloning https://github.com/JRiggles/jriggles.github.io.git into /Users/jriggles/Documents/GitHub/jriggles.github.io/node_modules/.cache/gh-pages/https!github.com!JRiggles!jriggles.github.io.git
GH-PAGES 28395: Cleaning
GH-PAGES 28395: Fetching origin
GH-PAGES 28395: Checking out origin/gh-pages 
GH-PAGES 28395: Removing files
GH-PAGES 28395: Copying files
GH-PAGES 28395: Adding all
GH-PAGES 28395: Committing
GH-PAGES 28395: Pushing
Published
```

And it appears to "publish" without any errors. But when I look at the `main` branch of https://github.com/JRiggles/jriggles.github.io it appears that the deployment action hasn't run and the `gh-pages` branch hasn't been updated.

The last time I got the deployment to work, something got mixed up during the build and my CSS broke - you can see the result of that mess at https://jriggl.es (I've also included some partial screenshots below)

For additional context I'm using Pug and Bulma to build the site and Parcel to put everything together. My `packages.json` includes these scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "copy static files": "mkdir ./dist/static && cp ./src/img/IQS5xx.py.svg ./dist/static/",
    "dev": "npx parcel src/index.pug",
    "predeploy": "rm -rf .parcel-cache && rm -rf dist && npx parcel build src/index.pug --public-url 'https://github.com/JRiggles/jriggles.github.io' && cp CNAME ./dist && npm run 'copy static files'",
    "deploy": "npx gh-pages -d dist",
    "clean gh-pages cache": "node node_modules/gh-pages/bin/gh-pages-clean"
},
```

...and these dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-pug": "^2.12.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.12.0",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "feather-icons": "^4.29.1"
  },
```

I remove `.parcel-cache` during predeploy to avoid other issues, but as you can see I've also tried cleaning the `gh-pages` module cache (to no avail). I've also tried removing `node_modules/.cache` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520448/the-following-paths-are-ignored-by-one-of-your-gitignore-files-node-modules/75563910#75563910)

I've also made sure node and my dependencies are up to date. And on the off-chance it makes any difference at all, I'm running Mac OS Sonoma 14.3.1 and working in VS Code.

For completeness' sake, here's a clip of what the site looks like when running on `localhost:1234` via `npm run dev`
[image: dev screenshot]

And heres what it looks like at the actual URL (if you don't feel like clicking the link above)
[image: as-deployed screenshot]

That is of course assuming I can get the deployment to work at all...this was the result of deployment #38, approximately 18 hours ago at time of writing. I have tried to deploy multiple times since then and had nothing happen.

Any help is very much appreciated - and thank you in advance for sticking with me through the long post.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of poking around, I tried changing the `--public-url` passed to `parcel`, and that seems to have fixe the issue

```
"predeploy": ... --public-url 'https://jriggles.github.io' ..."
```

As it turns out, the other URL was causing my custom domain to run into 404 errors because it couldn't locate my CSS or JS files on GitHub. I hope this helps somebody else avoid my mistake(s)!